# How to resize lvm partition on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: partitioning, 17.10, lvm, resize

How do I resize lvm partition on ubuntu 17.10 without loss of data?

Comment: gparted is a popular program to manage discs. have you tried that?

Comment: @Promille it doesn't resize lvm